# How can I change the corner radius of Material Components Dialog (M3) in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-components-android

See the pic at [here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8ChV9ZXTL1eb2tWMArrvN1I5tofFH9xzT2thUkm4ifLGSq4w1E3OVKdQ9PXsKrrStMA6VMOEVXMBTJfDbr7CtRm2xo1QteldPabtO0Go8JQ=s0)

I'm using MDC(3) for my project as first time and everything is going well until I see the dialog. What is wrong with that?

According per docs the size of corner radius is **28dp**

How can I reduce the size of corner radius?

**Update** here my code (I just updated according to [@che10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15690398/che10)'s answer

**themes.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.Material3">
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.Material3.MediumComponent">
        <item name="cornerSize">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

**In Java**

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this,R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_App)
```

It's still showing the same corner radius like default (28dp)

Answer (score 0):

Create and add the following things in your `styles.xml`

```xml
<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.Material3">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent</item>
</style>
```

```xml
<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.Material3.MediumComponent">
    <item name="cornerSize">20dp</item>
</style>
```

When instantiating your MaterialAlertDialogBuilder, pass it directly there and you should be good to go. Something like this

```kotlin
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext(), R.style.MaterialAlertDialog.App)
```

You can find more info here:
https://m3.material.io/components/dialogs/implementation/android

I think you also need to modify the `themes.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App</item>
</style>
```

Comment: In case you missed I'm using MDC Version 1.5.0. They already replaced ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents with ThemeOverlay.Material3

Comment: @RocketDev My bad. I missed it. Still the process will remain the same, just the parent theme will get update. Let me update it.

Comment: I appreciate your help but it's didn't work like what I want. I just updated the post maybe helpful for you to get my question. Thank dude.

Comment: @RocketDev I missed out some steps, you also need to modify the `themes.xml` and looking at the material documentation, it is possible to modify the corner radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom `ThemeOverlay`:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.Material3">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.Material3.MediumComponent">
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Then just use:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_MaterialAlertDialog)
```

[image]